# CarPlay with different audio source?

Tags: iphone, audio, car-integration

I just got my first ever car with CarPlay (along with Bluetooth and an aux port), and I’m about to break it in on a road trip with my friend next week. The one issue is, I’m not much of an audiophile, my friend’s usually the one who provides the music. What’s the easiest way to have the car run my CarPlay but play music from my friend’s phone?

Comment: Never actually tried it, but does it have 2 USB inputs? [good for charging too, Bluetooth will kill your charge]. Bluetooth is fine for short trips, USB is for 'journeys'. I'm sure, ultimately, it will involve sitting in the car, engine off, faffing around for half an hour... it usually does ;-) CarPlay is great, once you have it tailored to your precise requirements, but 'flexible'... not so much.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope, one USB port. It’s got two car outlets as well, so power’s never gonna be an issue if I have the right chargers, but only one USB input.